# Unable to add margin right to relative layout

Tags: android

I trying to add margin right to my relative layout. I need to add it in to HorizontalScrollView and bind data through java code. I have created layout file and add that file using layout inflator.

[image: Image here]

Below is my code:
XML Code:

```
                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/propertyListView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:fillViewport="true"
                        android:measureAllChildren="false"
                        android:scrollbars="none">


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/propertyListViewContainer"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">


                        </LinearLayout>
                    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Below is layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/propertyImage"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image_ad_property" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/propertyPriceContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/propertyImage"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="₹ 1.25 cr onwards"
            android:textColor="#6a6a6a"
            android:textSize="12sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/propertyName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/propertyPriceContainer"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Park Royale"
        android:textColor="#353535"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/propertyPlace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/propertyName"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Gokhale Marg"
        android:textColor="#6b6b6b"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rateContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/propertyPriceContainer"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ratingImage1"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_rating_selected" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ratingImage2"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_rating_selected" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ratingImage3"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_rating_selected" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ratingImage4"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_rating_normal" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ratingImage5"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_rating_normal" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/varifiedContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rateContainer"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_verified" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeVerified"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:text="Verified"
            android:textColor="#6b6b6b"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is java file:

```
      LinearLayout propertyListViewContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.propertyListViewContainer);;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            RelativeLayout child = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_project_details_property_item, null);
            final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; //set height and width
            int dpWidthInPx = (int) (280 * scale); //set width
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsBuyRent = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(dpWidthInPx, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            paramsBuyRent.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 0);
            child.setLayoutParams(paramsBuyRent);
            propertyListViewContainer.addView(child);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsBuyRent = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(dpWidthInPx, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

to:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsBuyRent = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

OR

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsBuyRent = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Layout inflater's inflate method has a second parameter that takes root view as a parameter. If you don't provide it the margins will be ignored. So provide container view as the second parameter there. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        RelativeLayout child = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_project_details_property_item, propertyListViewContainer);
    }
```

This way there's no need to add the inflated view to the parent layout at the end as it will automatically be attached to the provided layout keeping it's margins intact.

Comment: Added below code still not working.

RelativeLayout child = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_project_details_property_item, propertyListViewContainer, false);

Comment: make third parameter true